# Does affect yellow warining on react-native app perfromance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react-native app, which sometime generating a yellow warning message. for example: when I delete a doc from firestor may that doc is not exists. So I want to know will affect this warning on my app performance? although I know when I build APK react-native will not show the warning message.

**And why I am not catching the error, because I need a super fast delettion, insertion and updating of data.**

for example:

the following code will generate a warning if the doc was not exists.

`storageRef.child('images/desert.jpg').delete();`

but the following will not show any warning because I am catching it.

`storageRef.child('images/desert.jpg').delete().catch(err=>{});`

Why I dont want to use `catch(err=>{})` function?

**First:** without `catch()` function my code looks pretty.
**Second:** I think calling any extra function will take any extra time.

So by calling `catch()` function may code works slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I want to know will affect this warning on my app performance?

Yellow warning in React-native often reveals possible pitfall or unoptimized code in your app. In some cases, yes it affects the performance. In your case, it might not be.

> the following code will generate a warning if the doc was not exists.
>
> ```
> storageRef.child('images/desert.jpg').delete();
> ```

Aside from nonexistent doc, there are a wide range of errors that it might fall into, e.g. losing connection with server or anything within [this list from Google Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors). So not catching error will not allow you to know why it fails, nor inform app user about the failure properly.

> And why I am not catching the error, because I need a super fast
>   delettion, insertion and updating of data.

Unless you add anything inside catching function, cost to run an empty function `catch(err => {})` is almost negligible. On Chrome, [an empty function can be execute 100-500 operations per millisecond without trouble](https://jsperf.com/console-log1337/16), so I don't think in mobile it is slow enough to be considerable.

> I think calling any extra function will take any extra time.

True, but unless you want to do hundreds of operations at the same time, you will barely notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have some points to say here.

1. The fact of the yellow warning won't make your app slowly and less knowing that they won't be created in the production app (when the app is ready builded). But anyway, probably, the not caching error would produce a slowdown if the error that have been produce is relevant to the performance.
2. Then knowing this, I would recommend you to catch your errors due too would be reproduced a case where because fo that error you would see that your app is getting slow but you don't know where, and you don't have the catch to see the error and maybe that's would be the problem. To put catch in the end of the line to make your code more save doesn't really mean that it would look uglier.